# Volumes by Slices

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

The base of a solid is the region in the xy-plane bounded by the curves $ y = \sqrt x, x=4,$ and $y = 0$. Cross-sections of the solid perpendicular to the x-axis are semicircles. Find its volume.

I solved the following integral, adding a coefficient of $\frac1 2$ because the cross section is a semicircle, thus a half rotation. I get a final answer of $4\pi$ as follows:

$$ V = \frac \pi2 \int_0^4 \sqrt x ^2 \,dx = \frac \pi2  \int_0^4 x dx = \frac \pi4 x^2 \bigg|_0^4 = 4\pi $$

The computer says this answer is incorrect. Am I misinterpreting the axis of rotation?

Comment: It looks OK to me

Comment: How are the semicircles positioned with respect to the $x$-axis?

Comment: I have edited the title, as this is not a solid of revolution: the volume is found by the method of "slicing".

Comment: @DMcMor 's answer is correct. This problem was set up like a washer when it is not a rotation. The "base" of the semicircles must lie in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  A "washer" is not being used; the title of the post was misleading.  Semi-circular slices set up on the region in the $ \ xy-$ plane _are_ being used, but the radius of the slices was incorrect, as explained in the answer below.

Comment: @boojum except the way OP set up the problem is exactly how you would set up a rotation, which is what I was talking about, and why some of us missed the mistake on first glance, because it was a correct set up for that.

Comment: +1 for what the comment of  @NinadMunshi  indicated, which is also how I initially interpreted the problem: you were being asked to compute the volume of a *solid of revolution* about the $x$-axis.  In fact, this *natural* interpretation **must be in error** because it **conflicts** with : " The base of a solid is the region in the xy-plane bounded by the curves $ y = \sqrt x, x=4,$ and $y = 0$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the solid has semicircular cross sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis, the area of one of these cross sections is $$\frac{1}{2}\pi r^{2} = \frac{1}{2}\pi \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^{2} = \frac{\pi x}{8}.$$  The total volume then is given by $$V = \int_{0}^{4}\frac{\pi x}{8}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{16}x^{2}\bigg|_{0}^{4} = \pi.$$  Your error was in that you said that the radius of the semicircles was $\sqrt{x}$, where in reality this is the diameter.